# Node js - overall structure of a program

Tags: node.js

Hope you are well.

I need your help to understand how to logically organize a program in Node JS to avoid repetition of code given its asynchronous property (as a beginner ..). Let's take an example to make it easier to explain.
One has some data in a mongo database (let's say a list of name). This list of name can be access thanks to the function readData as below

```
function readData(criteriaRead,callback) {
    mongodb.stuff(..)
    callback('data read on mongodb')
}
```

I have two actions in my program: one is to print out the list of name, the other is to check if a name is in the list.
For the first case, it's simple, I just need to have a function like this

```
function printout(data) {console.log(data)}
```

and to do this

```
readData(criteriaRead,printout)
```

In the second case, let's say I have a function like this

```
checkIfInIt(array,dataToCheck) {//stuff to check console.log(results)}
```

Now, I have an issue because if I do`readData(criteriaRead,checkIfInIt)` it won't work as checkIfInIt requires two parameters.
I would need a function like this

```
function readDataBis(criteriaRead,dataToCheck,callback) {
    mongodb.stuff(..)
    callback('data read on Mongodb','dataToCheck')
}
```

and then `readDataBis(criteriaRead,dataToCheck,checkIfInIt)` would work but I have a huge repetition in my code.

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions for this type of issue, but here's an easy one for your case

Declare your function with the three parameters as such

```
function readData(callback, criteriaRead, dataToCheck) { ...
```

Inside, check if `dataToCheck` is `undefined`, and continue with the flow of the second function you had if that's the case. (Otherwise just do the read function)

Call them like so

```
readData(callback, criteriaRead); // Third parameter missing, will be undefined
readData(callback, criteriaRead, dataToCheck);
```

You could also pass in an object for your parameters like this, if it would make it simpler

```
function readData(callback, params) { ...
```

And call like this

```
readData(callback, { criteriaRead: criteriaRead, dataToCheck: dataToCheck });
```

Comment: Well, your second solution is perfect for my case - especially because I can keep all my data across the different callbacks. That's wonderful, thanks a lot

Comment: I thought about this during the night. Would it be possible to do the same with the callback function?

Comment: Do the same what?

Comment: Sorry for not having answered ! I meant having an object { 'id':function(), 'id2': function()} in order to store the functions and pass them through the different steps. It seems to work fine !